# Java Pyramid output

Tags: java

Hi all I am trying to create a pyramid program that asks a user for int between 1-15. When I enter 1-9 it creates a perfect pyramid. But if I enter 10-15 the line down the middle goes to right with each number pass 10 no longer making a pyramid.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-15");
    int dig = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= dig; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= dig - i; j++) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }

        for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--) {
            System.out.print("  " + k);
        }

        for (int k = 2; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print("  " + k);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Because 10-15 take up two character spaces, you'll want to compensate for this in rows 1-9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still achieve the same result with your code but rather than use the *print* method, use the *printf* method that takes a format specifier as the first parameter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-15");
    int dig = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= dig; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= dig - i; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%4s", " ");
        }
        for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--) {
            System.out.printf("%4d", k);
        }
        for (int k = 2; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.printf("%4d", k);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here each integer that is printed out is padded with additional spaces, by specifying a fixed width of 4 characters, therefore compensating for integers that can either be one or two characters long.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :).

You have to count the number of digits of the max number and then create bigger spaces at beginning, but start to make them smaller when two-digit number comes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-15");
    int dig = input.nextInt();
    int length = ("" + dig).length();
    for (int i = 1; i <= dig; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= dig - i; j++) {
            for (int f = 0; f < length; f++) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < length - (""+k).length() + 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(k);
        }

        for (int k = 2; k <= i; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < length - (""+k).length() + 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(k);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output for 15 :

```
Enter a number between 1-15
15
                                                                          1
                                                                     2    1    2
                                                                3    2    1    2    3
                                                           4    3    2    1    2    3    4
                                                      5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5
                                                 6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6
                                            7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
                                       8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
                                  9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
                            10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
                       11   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
                  12   11   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
             13   12   11   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
        14   13   12   11   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
   15   14   13   12   11   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Number of rows to print Pyramid: ");
    int rows= scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();
    
    
    String star="*";
    
    
    System.out.println("========================================");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j =0; j<=rows-i ; j++) {

            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        
        for(int k=0; k<=i; k++) {
            System.out.print(star + " ");
            
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output for 5:

```
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

---

---